# Critical points in Hilbert space

Tags: critical-point-theory, calculus-of-variations

Let $f$ be a $C^1$ functional on a Hilbert space $X$, and $Y$ a closed subspace of $X$.
Suppose the restriction of $f$ on $Y$ has a critical point $x_0 \in Y$.

Q: Is $x_0$ a critical point of $f$?

Comment: Of course not. Take e.g. $f$ a non-zero linear functional and Y=ker(f).

Comment: (or also, whatever X and f, and Y=(0)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especially in Calculus of Variations and Mechanics, a submanifold $Y$ of a manifold $X$ is usually called "a natural constraint" for a functional $f$ on $X$, if the special circumstance that you are considering does happen: constrained critical points of $f$ on $Y$ are free critical points:  $\operatorname{crit} (f_{|Y})\subset \operatorname{crit}(f)$.

An important situation when this is true arises when $Y$ is defined as fixed point set of a group of symmetries of $f$. The corresponding principle, claiming that $Y$ is a natural constraint,  is  known since old times as a popular proverb. In the late 70' Richard Palais has made this into a deep and beautiful theorem, stating the right hypotheses for its validity and also providing counter-examples to the naive claim of the principle (all popular proverbs are 95% true but never 100% true!). [ R. Palais, *The Principle of Symmetric Criticality*, Comm. Math. Phys., Vol. 69, Number 1 (1979),  19-30 ]